# How to modify part of the design of the details of the article magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php, layout

I want to be able to modify a part of the page of the details of the products of magento 2

[image]

The marked part is the one that I want to be able to edit, add or remove content is that section.

So far I can modify the title, the price and the description below, but how do I manage to manipulate that section? From the admin panel is the content section. I have tried so

```
public function afterLoad(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
{
    $subject->setData('content', $subject->getContent() . '- TEST CONTENT');
    return $result;
}
```

But it does not work, how can I solve it?

And this is my di.xml file

```
<config>
  <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
    <plugin name="change_product" type="Devchannel\HelloWorld\Plugin\Product " sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
  </type>
</config>
```

[image]

Comment: Mentioned section is blank. What do you want to do?

Comment: @SukumarGorai The section is white because that article has it empty, but there are others that have content, what I need is to be able to modify it, in the view of the admin is the content section

Comment: @SukumarGorai Add another photo where there is content in that section